# JQuery Stop any other events and functions until this event finishes

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

So on my website, I have a circle. When you hover over the circle, it grows and takes over the whole page and becomes a menu. This is done with jQuery:

```
$(".fullScreenMenu").hover(function(){
   $('.fullScreenMenuText').fadeOut();
   $(".fullScreenMenu").css("transform", "scale(20)", "top", "-30vh", "left","-30vw", "transition-duration", "2s"); 
   $("#menuTest").fadeIn();
});
```

This works just fine. However, I don't want it to close when the user moves off hover. Instead, I have an 'x' that pops up on the nav menu.

```js
$(".fullScreenMenu").hover(function(){
   $('.fullScreenMenuText').fadeOut();
   $(".fullScreenMenu").css("transform", "scale(20)", "top", "-30vh", "left","-30vw", "transition-duration", "2s"); 
   $("#menuTest").fadeIn();
});
$('#closeBtn').click(function(){ 
      $(".fullScreenMenu").css("transform", "scale(1)", "top", "80vh", "left","-2vw", "transition-duration", ".5s"); 
    $("#menuTest").fadeOut();   
     function showCircleText(){
        $('.fullScreenMenuText').show(); 
      }
    setTimeout(showCircleText, 500);
    });
```

```css
   .close {
     position: fixed;
     top: 5vh;
     text-align: right;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- FULL SCREEN MENU -->
    <div class="fullScreenMenu">
    <div class="fullScreenMenuText">Full Screen Menu</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="menuTest">
     <div class="text-center col-12 mt-5">
  <div class="display-2 text-center" style="z-index: 200">This is a Menu Test</div>
  <h1 style="z-index: 200">This is a Menu Test</h1>
 </div>
 
 <div class="close col-12">
  <h1><i class="fas fa-times" id="closeBtn"></i></h1>
 </div> 
</div>
```

This also works fine...sometimes. If you move the mouse AT ALL after you've clicked the 'x' it re-triggers the $(".fullScreenMenu").hover(function(){...}; function. Basically, all I want to do is prevent any other JQuery from working for the 1 second it takes to do the closing animation.

I tried event.stopImmediatePropagation(); and event.stopPropagation(); but neither of those worked (based on their descriptions, I didn't think they'd work anyway).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a flag, like canAnimate, when the close button is clicked and not open or do anything on hover while the flag is true.

```
    var canAnimate = true;
    $(".fullScreenMenu").hover(function(){
       if(canAnimate){   
          $('.fullScreenMenuText').fadeOut();
          $(".fullScreenMenu").css("transform", "scale(20)", "top", "-30vh", "left","-30vw", "transition-duration", "2s"); 
          $("#menuTest").fadeIn();
       }
    });

    function showCircleText(){
       $('.fullScreenMenuText').show(); 
       canAnimate = true;
    }

    $('#closeBtn').click(function(){ 
       canAnimate = false;
       $(".fullScreenMenu").css("transform", "scale(1)", "top", "80vh", "left","-2vw", "transition-duration", ".5s");

       $("#menuTest").fadeOut();
       setTimeout(showCircleText, 500);
    });
```

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly. I guess I was severely overthinking it. I appreciate it!